# Why is the hair in these models not rendering as I expect?

Tags: modeling, hair

I downloaded [these](https://www.cgtrader.com/items/4510460/download-page) [two](https://www.cgtrader.com/items/4045084/download-page) models to play with, and importing them into blender, their hair is obviously recognised in some respect, but not how it should be... anyone know what I'm doing/is going wrong?

[image: Matt]

[image: Amber]

Comment: in the Particles panel, under Children, is the Render Amount the same as Display Amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hair material has a transparency map and you are rendering the models in *Eevee*, which is in my opinion not great for objects with transparency. Most likely your hair material is set to the default *Blend Mode* > *Alpha Blend*. Switch it to *Alpha Hashed* for all hair materials (and the "Scalp Transparency" material), this should look better:

[image: alpha hashed eevee]

A much better result you get rendering in *Cycles* without the need to change any setting on the hair materials:

[image: cycles hair]

Comment: That's it, thanks very much - I always forget new scenes default to Eevee!

Comment: @JohnGraham If you don't want to use _Eevee_ by default, open a brand new scene, switch the render engine to _Cycles_ and go to _File_ > _Defaults_ > _Save Startup File_.